# Doubled auto start entry for Google chrome?

Tags: gnome, google-chrome

It seems that Chrome adds two autostart entries to the Gnome auto start configuration:

1. Google Chrome =>  /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --no-startup-window
2. Google Chrome Service => /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=service

Is this correct? Because I often get errors about "chrome already running".

Answer (score 1):

It's 100% okay. The first one - `google-chrome --no-startup-window` is default chrome process starter, which makes the user experience much more fluent (for opening new browser windows etc).
The second  - `chrome --type=service` is chrome printing service (you can disable/enable it in chrome settings).

Comment: Disabling the chrome printing services seems to solve the problem. But I don't understand why turning this on leads to conflicts? If the feature is enabled I receive errors about "unavailable profile" etc.

Comment: I've seen just a few people asking for help about the same issue, I think you'd need to go to chrome product forum: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/chrome

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-linux-google-chrome-browser-download-install-and-usage) article may help in search for you answer, It is a little old now but still appears to be relevant.

"
6. Howto Start Google Chrome Browser

> Once the Google Chrome installation is complete simply navigate to (
>   Gnome GUI ) "Applications->Internet->Google Chrome" . Google Chrome
>   installed itself into /opt/google/chrome/ directory. It is also
>   possible to start Google chrome from a command line by execution of a
>   following command:
>
> `ubuntu-chrome ~$ google-chrome`
>
> Google chrome installer had additionally created few symbolic links to
>   integrate the browser to our GUI environment and for this reason
>   Google chrome browser can also be started from a command line using
>   these alternative commands:

```
> ubuntu-chrome ~$ /usr/bin/x-www-browser
> ubuntu-chrome ~$ /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser
```

> The preceding commands are symbolic links all the way to the actual
>   Google chrome executable binary located within
>   /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome For example,
>   /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser points to
>   /etc/alternatives/gnome-www-browser which points to
>   /usr/bin/google-chrome which leads to /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
>   and therefore, any of the listed commands can be used to successfully
>   start Google chrome browser. Additionally, upon the first start of
>   Google chrome browser a ~/.config/google-chrome/ directory will be
>   created, which will store all users individual browser settings.
>   Google Chrome will then generously offer you a choice to choose your
>   default search engine to search the web using the omnibox. This is
>   kind of nice o have a choice, and it proves that Google is not afraid
>   of its direct competitors since Google knows that its position on the
>   search engine market will be not that easily shaken. Select a default
>   search engine for Google Chrome:
>   "